# magento category url,admin 404 error

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am a magento newbie.
I've observed that when I make an installation of magento by copying all contents of the extraction directly to localhost.... i.e (when app, media, skin, index.php etc all pasted directly in localhost) I am unable to access the admin by simply typing in localhost/admin.
Whereas I have to type in localhost/index.php/admin to get into the admin panel.

Also when i click on any category i have the same problem.
I have to append index.php/ before the category name to get the category link working.

Can anyone please tell me how to get them working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Base URL in the Admin Panel, go to System | Configuration | Web and make sure the Secure and Unsecure Base URL does not include the 'index.php' part.

If you do not have index.php in my secure or unsecure web configuration and this happening on front end and back end, try to enable url rewrites and see if that solves it. You need mod_rewrite enabled on your localhost.

What is your local server?

Comment: I did'nt have index.php in the secure and unsecure base URLs. However I had URL rewrites enabled, so I disabled (not enabled) URL rewrites and its working fine. Thanks a lot